# What does centre of positive and negative charge separated by a small distance mean?

Tags: electrostatics, polarization, dipole, dipole-moment

[image]

I dont understand the meaning of this statement that centre of positive and negative charge is separated by a small distance??

Comment: You find the answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775436/what-does-centre-of-mass-of-charge-mean

Comment: I just see that this is almost the same question you asked here  physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775436/…