# What does centre of mass of charge mean?

Tags: electrostatics, polarization, dipole, dipole-moment

[image]

I am unable to understand what does this centre of mass of positive charge and centre of mass of negative charge mean??

Comment: I am not sure but I  believe that the charged particles have a mass and the centre of mass of charges refer to the centre of mass of the charged particles.

Comment: Centre ofmass is of a continuous body …..and the charges spreaded over in space have a centre of mass doesnt make any sense

Comment: The centre of mass of a continuous body absolutely makes sense.

Comment: I think you didnt see i image i attached to the question it is written that the charge we are taking is of electrons and it cannot be taken ascontinuous!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have $n$ point charges located at positions $\vec{r}_1,...,\vec{r}_n$ and carrying charges $q_1,...,q_n$, then the center-of-charge $\vec{R}$ of the point charges is given by

$
\displaystyle\vec{R}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nq_i\vec{r}_i}{\sum_{i=1}^nq_i}
$

Comment: I think the appearance of "mass" is confusing. They mean the "centre of charge",  I.e the quantity ${\bf R}$ in @CW279's answer but with the $m_i$ replaced by  the charges $q_i$. This is what is needed to get the electric dipole moment. Mass has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @mikestone I completely agree. I've adjusted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Does that even mean anything since charge is signed? Is it independent of the origin?  Of course it diverges too

Comment: OP's article talks about the "centre of mass of negative charges". The formula for $\vec{R}$ seems sensible if it's used to calculate the COM of positive/negative charges separately.